# What's a world boss?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've seen a "world boss" referenced several times, but have yet to see any quest that leads to something that seems like a "boss" for the world.  So what's a world boss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, they are "world-level" bosses (not found in instanced, repeatable adventures) that require more than a 4 person party. Usually an operation of 12-16 players (of the appropriate level) are recommend for going against them.

The world boss mobs are usually massive and have an indication saying "World Boss" when you select them.

[Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/swtor/comments/n8c5a/world_boss_locations/) is a list of world boss locations.

Comment: Beating a world boss also adds an entry to your Codex.

Comment: They also tend to drop good loot, and are needed for some weekly/daily quests.

Answer (score 5):

A world boss is an enemy that exists in the open world, they are not locked into any Flashpoints, Operations, or Story area. Anyone can attack him, but generally one or two players will not be able to take them down (unless they are really high level and have great gear).

They generally do not have a quest associated to them, but generally drop good pieces of equipment/weapons for any heroes strong enough to kill them.

So far I have encountered 2 such world bosses. One exists in the middle of nowhere in the Dune Sea on Tatoonine and the other is a giant robot in Shadow Town on Nar Shaddaa Co-ords (2093, 2910). Both these bosses have over 500,000 health.

Comment: there is an other world boss on Curuscant too, I'll add details when I go back there.

Answer (score 5):

> what's a world boss?

Here's a world boss.

[image: SD0]

From the hitpoints (191k) and considering an attacker might do 400 damage per attack, it would take ~475 attacks to kill.

With x attackers, it would take y attacks to down (assuming no defensive specials, no additions, no boss heals).

- 3 attackers, ~150 attacks each.
- 10 attackers, ~50 attacks each.
- 20 attackers, ~24 attacks each.

Based on my healing characters running out of resources at ~30 actions, it seems this boss would require between 10 and 20 attackers.

Comment: To Downvoters: care to comment?

Comment: You've provided a picture of one particular boss with no additional information. This is of little use and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Do I think this is the definitive answer? No.  Do I think this is useful?  Yes - in the same way "What is a rhinocerus?" could be answered.

Comment: I agree that it is useful to have an example, especially with the tooltip. However, a better way to contribute is to edit the original answer and add your image to it.